# "assigned randomly" or "randomly assigned"?

Tags: word-usage

I am creating a simulation that has 10 units and each unit gets either a squid, a fish, or a person.

Here is my example sentence: "A squid, a fish, or a person is randomly assigned to each unit."

It could also read: "A squid, a fish, or a person is assigned randomly to each unit."

Do I say that the units are randomly assigned or assigned randomly?

Comment: Adverbs in passive constructions can be very troublesome. Particularly when they seem to want to impart a character trait to the agent. So a progy uses a random function call to assign either a squid, fish, or human to each unit. The random notion is in reality a characteristic of the subject. This is different from the manner notion of the adverb *randomly*. We don't say "the distance was squarerootingly extracted from the sum of the vector component magnitudes". Better not to use adverbs as zombie agents in passive constructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word `randomly` is an adverb of manner.
In the above context, it describes the way the units are assigned.

As an adverb of manner, it is positioned [before the verb or at the end of the clause](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position).

To emphasize the manner, the latter---"randomly assigned"---is preferred.

Compare :

- The simulation *randomly* assigned a label to each unit.
- The simulation assigns a label to each unit *randomly*.
- The simulation assigns a label to each unit *in a random manner*.

The second and third sentences draw the reader attention to the word `randomly`.

Comment: Or "A label is assigned *randomly* to each unit by the simulation." Your answer is incomplete and doesn't actually address the question of order that was asked.

Comment: I don't know why this was down-voted; seems like a reasonable response.

Comment: @vy32: probably because it's incomplete. For example, you could also say *The simulation assigns a label randomly to each unit.* What you want to avoid doing is putting the adverb between the verb and its object.

Comment: @JasonBassford, okay, I have added a clear example. Which is correct?